# Linking a button to a new pageor activity screen

Tags: android, android-layout, android-button

I'm new to Android app development,I would like to know how to link a button to another new page.I was confused by terms such as event listeners and many.Could some one kindly help me linking a button to a new page where I can create further more?

Which code should I modify and how?

Comment: Hi pranavg welcome to stackoverflow. Pleas pest your code what you have tried till now, you will get help if there is any error.

Answer (score 0):

you need to `setOnClickListener()` of your button and use `intent` to call next activity.

Example:

```
public class YourActivity extends Activity
{
Button mybutton;
 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    mybutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    mybutton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(YourActivity.this, NextActivity.class);
            YourActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
 }
}
```

Don't forget to add your new activity in the AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<activity android:label="@string/app_name" android:name=".NextActivity"/>
```

Comment: Where should I insert this snippet ? under which code or option?

Comment: you can use it in onCreate() or onResume() methods

Comment: how do i use the oncreate or onresume method,under where do i get that ?

Comment: @pranavg it is an android activity lifecycle method, you can override this method in your own activity class using `@Override`

Comment: you can go through http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html
link for more detail

Answer (score 0):

```
Button btnTest;

public class myactivity extends Activity {
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity);

        btnTest =(Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_Test);
                btnTest.setOnClickListener(OpenNewActivity);

    }

}

View.OnClickListener OpenNewActivity = new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent intent = new Intent(myactivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);


        }
    };
```

You have to register your second activity also in Manifest.xml

```
<activity android:name=".SecondActivity">            
        </activity>
```

inside `<application> </application>`